# Calculate position of an Image in Absolutelayout when zooming

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Page which contains an `AbsoluteLayout` with a `PinchZoomContainer` (like the one from microsoft docs). In this Container is an image that fills the entire screen. When the user tapes on the image, another image (a pin) is positioned at the tappostion. So far this works. My problem is, that i couldn't figure out, how to calculate the position of the added image (user tapped) when the user zooms in and out.

I want the added image to stay at the tapped position, no matter if the user zooms in or out.
When i put the image in a grid the calculation gets done automatically.

Is there a better way to achieve that? I've chosen `AbsoluteLayout` because i need to put the image at the tapped position.

The following code is used for zooming. Here I can't figure out how to do the calculation for the added image. The image gets added to the `AbsoluteLayout` on runtime.

[Normal scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv9EC.jpg)

[Zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6FO8.jpg)

```
void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
        {
            // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
            // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
            startScale = Content.Scale;
            Content.AnchorX = 0;
            Content.AnchorY = 0;
            startTransX = pin.TranslationX;
            startTranxY = pin.TranslationY;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
        {
            // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
            currentScale = currentScale + (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
            currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);
           
            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the X pixel coordinate.
            double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
            double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
            double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
            double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
            double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
            double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
            double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
            double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

            // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
            double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
            double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

            // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
            // needs to use Xamarin.Forms.Internals or Extension

            Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
            Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
            
            x = Content.TranslationX;
            y = Content.TranslationY;
            
            // Apply scale factor
            Content.Scale = currentScale;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
        {
            // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
            x = Content.TranslationX;
            y = Content.TranslationY;
        }
    }
```

Comment: without seeing any code it's difficult to provide specfic advice.  But this seems like a pretty basic math/geometry problem - track the coordinates of the pin relative to the original image.  As you zoom the image just adjust the coordinates by the scale factors.  This is the kind of thing where a pencil and some graph paper can be really helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't attach a screenshot. The added image stays in the same place when "dragging" with the finger, but not when zooming. The code for dragging is simply the delta from the previous location. But this does not work for zooming as there is scaling involved.

Comment: as I said before, you probably need to add (or modify) the zoom logic to account for the scaling

Comment: Yes thats the problem. I want the same behaviour like google maps. You place a pin at the map and it stays right there when you move or zoom the map. Thats what I want to do but I fail at the calculation :(

Comment: I would overlay a second AbsoluteLayout that does not zoom. Put the pin in that non-zooming layout. Overlay using single cell grid: `<Grid> <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="layout1" ... > ... </AbsoluteLayout> <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="layout2" ... > ... </AbsoluteLayout> </Grid>`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks it works now! You have set me on the right path. In your example the problem is, that the pin stays at the position when zooming but not in relation to the backgroundimage. So if I set the pin right at the sun (in the example image) it moves a bit around depending on the actual scaling factor.